# How can I set up a portable dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to figure out the best setup for dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 to allow me to simply image it directly to another computer and have it just work.

There are a few problems that I've run into.

Firstly, GRUB 2 matches UUIDs so you either have to reinstall GRUB or change the UUIDs. Is there any way to automate this UUID matching?

Another problem that I'm having (but this may be a question geared more towards a Windows forum), is the Windows BCD seems to get messed up when transferring from a SATA drive to a NVMe drive.

Comment: The purpose of this is hopefully to have an admistrative image of one system and be able to distribute that image to multiple systems. Some of the systems may be running NVMe drives and other SATA drives.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you changing partitions you need run Ubuntu and run command `update-grub` (be sure you have installed os-prober, it detects other operation systems)